# Incorrect value returned by ISO_C_binding "c_intptr_t" in Fortran / Mac OS X

Tags: c, macos, gcc, fortran

I have the following Fortran function `create_pointer` that calls a C function named `create_pointer` that creates a pointer and returns its address:

```
FUNCTION create_pointer() RESULT(c_intptr_t) BIND(C, name = "create_pointer")
    USE, INTRINSIC :: iso_c_binding, ONLY: c_intptr_t
END FUNCTION
```

For reference, the C function `create_pointer` is the following:

```
intptr_t create_pointer(void)
{
    void *ptr;
    intptr_t address;

    ptr = malloc(100);
    address = (intptr_t) ptr;
    printf("FROM C: address %p\n", address)
    return address;
}
```

Now, when compiling (using GCC 4.9) and executing the following Fortran program in Mac OS X 64 bit:

```
PROGRAM

    INTEGER(c_intptr_t) :: address

    address = create_pointer()

    WRITE(*, '(Z8)') "FROM FORTRAN:", address

END PROGRAM
```

It gives an unexpected output which could be similar to this:

```
FROM C: address 0x7f8870c3ee00
FROM FORTRAN: address 70C3EE00
```

Why is the address being displayed in C different from the one in Fortran? I would assume that ISO_C_binding `c_intptr_t` would preserve the correct value between these two languages. Additionally, as one can notice, the address that Fortran receives from C is contained within it (in other words, the initial value 0x7f88 is discarded). Is it because only the first 48 bit in a 64 bit address count and the ISO_C_binding discards the last 16 bit?

FYI, when compiling (using GCC 4.9) and running the same Fortran program this time in Ubuntu 64 bit, the output is consistent (i.e. both the address that C and Fortran display are the same).

Comment: On the Mac, are you sure you're using the actual GCC and not Clang (as the `gcc` and `g++` commands are linked to by default)?

Comment: Yes, it's GCC. When running `gfortran -v` and `gcc -v` they both return `gcc version 4.9.4 (MacPorts gcc49 4.9.4_3)`.

Comment: Are you sure `WRITE(*, '(Z8)') "FROM FORTRAN:", address` gives you the output you describe?

Comment: Yes, I'm absolutely sure.

Comment: `70c3ee00` is the low 32 bits of the address.  This suggests that `c_intptr_t` is incorrectly defined as a 32- rather than 64-bit quantity.  I don't know how you declare a 64-bit integer in Fortran, but if you change the Fortran-side declaration of `address` and the RESULT declaration on `create_pointer` to whatever that is, do you now get the correct value?

Comment: @zwol, usually `c_intptr_t` will automatically have the size of 4 bytes if compiled for 32 bit, or 8 bytes if compiled for 64 bit, so I don't think the issue is there. Nonetheless, I have tried with `c_int64_t` and `c_long_long` and none of them worked (i.e. they display the same as `c_intptr_t`).

Comment: @francescalus That should probably be an answer, explaining that the number is the number of *digits* and not bytes.

Comment: @francescalus, I'm absolutely sure of the code and what is being printed. To test things further I even executed this line `WRITE(*, '(Z8)') address, SIZEOF(address)` and the output was something similar to this `70C3EE00       8`.

Comment: @francescalus, modifying `(Z8)` to `(Z16)` didn't change much things, except printing a bunch of `FF` as a prefix. This may indicate that a 32 bit number (i.e. address) is received, but both the C and Fortran code are compiled with the `-m64` flag, and I'm using `intptr_t` (in the C program) and `c_intptr_t` (in the Fortran program) so everything should work fine (i.e. with 64 bit addresses).

Comment: Thanks for confirming.  It _shouldn't_ have made any difference (after all, if too large for 8 digits one would expect `********`) as your output.

Comment: But now I've seen the problem: please add `implicit none` to your Fortran program.  Your function `create_pointer` is assumed to be returning a default real result because you haven't actually included the interface you've given in the main program.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments above; it helped to clarify some things!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your error is here:

```
FUNCTION create_pointer() RESULT(c_intptr_t) BIND(C, name = "create_pointer")
```

You are supposed to put a variable name inside the `result` part of a function declaration. Then you can use the name you put there inside the body of the function, and the value it has when the function terminates will be the result value returned by the function.

In your code, you put the name `c_intptr_t`, which coincides with the name you just imported from the intrinsic module and you effectively overrides it. I don't think that's the intention.

Also, as said by @francescalus, you do not have `implicit none`, so you let the default [implicit rules](https://software.intel.com/en-us/fortran-compiler-18.0-developer-guide-and-reference-implicit-typing-rules) of Fortran choose the type of your result variable; and it chooses default real (because the variable name starts with the letter C) - that's why the pointer is 32 bits in size.

`c_intptr_t` is a [constant](http://fortranwiki.org/fortran/show/iso_c_binding)  inside the intrinsic module 
`iso_c_binding` meant to be used as a **type parameter** for interoperable integer that get the correct pointer size of the system.

You could change the name of the variable inside result, for example to `ptr`, and change your function declaration to this:

```
function create_pointer() result(ptr) bind(C, name = "create_pointer")
  use, intrinsic :: iso_c_binding, only: c_intptr_t
  implicit none
  integer(c_intptr_t) :: ptr
end function
```

Comment: Regarding "effectively overrides": the two uses are not allowed rather than the name of the function result hiding that of the used entity.  But that's fine, because the interface isn't included in any code compiled (that we can see).

Comment: That's what I mean by overriding: hiding.

Comment: But it isn't legitimate hiding: it's a violation of Fortran requirements.  You're quite right to say it's erroneous, but it's totally wrong rather than not what is intended.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the solution and the comments above, I managed to solve the issue by doing the following:

```
integer(c_intptr_t) function create_pointer() bind(C, name = "create_pointer")
    use, intrinsic :: iso_c_binding, only: c_intptr_t
end function
```